# How to compute the probability of trajectories term in Stochastic Gradient Meta Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, hessian

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.05135.pdf) introduces Stochastic Gradient Meta RL (SGMLR). My question is specifically about the computation. One needs to calculate the Hessian, $\nabla^2_\theta J_i(\theta)$ which is given by the following equations:
$$\nabla^2J_i(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim q_i(\cdot,\theta)}[u_i(\tau,\theta)]$$
where
$$u_i(\tau,\theta)=\nabla_\theta v_i\nabla_\theta \log q_i(\tau,\theta)^T+\nabla_\theta^2v_i(\tau,\theta)$$
where
$$v_i(\tau,\theta)=\sum_{h=0}^H\log\pi_i(a_h|s_h)\mathcal{R}_i^h(\tau)$$

My question is about the second equation, specifically the term $\nabla_\theta \log q_i(\tau,\theta)$, where $q_i(\tau,\theta)$ is the probability of trajectory $\tau=(s_0,a_0,s_1,a_1,...,s_H,a_H)$ if the policy has parameters $\theta$. More precisely, I don't know how to calculate/estimate that term, and unfortunately the paper does not address  that.

I was looking at their code [here](https://github.com/kristian-georgiev/SGMRL), but I can't seem to find where they calculate that term or what they do with that term. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of the trajectory should be $q(\tau, \theta) = Pi_{i=0}^H \pi(s_i, a_i | \theta)$. That’s at least how we calculate the importance sampling correction factor in off-policy learning.

I’m not familiar with using $q(., \theta)$ as notation for that though; I’m more familiar with $q$ being used to denote the function that estimates the action values. I would check out [Sutton & Barto as a reference for this (pdf free available online).

Comment: Yes, but in practice one doesn't have access to $P$. The authors do indicate that probability is given by: $q_i(\tau,\theta)=\prod_{h=0}^H\pi_i\prod_{h=0}^HP_i$. Do you know how to estimate that value in practice?